# Invalid xpath expression to find a slider element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, katalon-studio

Very new to Katalon Studio and selenium.  Trying to write an automated test using selenium webdriver to change the value of the slider on the webpage.
I am failing to locate the element. Somehting is wrong with my findelement statement.  Also once I locate the slider element successfully I don't know how to change the value of the slider.  Can you help? or provide some quidance?

```
 <div class="bdr-slider"
   <span id="bdrText">bdr Amount</span>
   <input min="0" max="15" step"0.5" value="5" type="range">
 </div>


 WebElement Slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("*[div(@class,'bdr-     slider')]"))
```

Comment: That is not valid XPath. Most XPath locations start with the `/` character and go from there. Maybe something like `//div[@class='bdr-slider']`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
`WebElement Slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='bdr-slider']"))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with specifics of mobile automation, but I think that you need to locate the input element. 
This one

```
<input min="0" max="15" step"0.5" value="5" type="range">
```

and then maybe call sendKeys method on that element.
You can try this line of code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='bdr-slider']/input")).sendKeys("10");
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I get this error message:     org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //div[@class='bdr-slider']/input

Answer (score 0):

Before proceeding, make sure the element is really present in the DOM, and thus making sure the problem is not with the path, enter $x('//div[@class="bdr-slider"]/input') to console in DevTools and see if you can locate the element.

If you can find the element, since you are using Katalon Studio, you can do this:

```
TestObject slider = new TestObject().addProperty('css', ConditionType.EQUALS, '.bdr-slider input')
```

or, if you prefer xpath:

```
 TestObject slider = new TestObject().addProperty('xpath', ConditionType.EQUALS, "//div[@class='bdr-slider']/input")
```

You will need to import these two:

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ConditionType
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject
```